# Xcode changes my credentials when adding a remote on GitHub

Tags: xcode, git

I can not get a project in Xcode to use my credentials when I add a remote, so I can pull the project from  GitHub and get updates. Any time I try to add a remote, using e.g., https://github.com/Example/ExampleProject.git Xcode changes it to to my buddy's GitHub user name. The result looks like this https://MyBuddy@github.com/Example/ExampleProject.git

Then if I try

https://Myusername@github.com/Example/ExampleProject.git it still changes it to  https://MyBuddy@github.com/Example/ExampleProject.git

When I try to create a new remote, it says that GitHub cannot be reached or does not exist so I cannot add GitHub as a server.

Perhaps I am doing this wrong.

How can I specify for Xcode to pull from GitHub, using my credentials? Everytime I try to pull now it says no remotes.

Comment: https://github.com/project.git doesn't exist. https://github.com/WIIJBD/project.git might. You need a username before the project name.

Comment: https://github.com/SomeInc/SomeIncProject.git, it isn't real its an example, I dont want to give the real project. but if i spcify the said url, xcode changes it to https://MyBuddy@github.com/SomeInc/SomeIncProject.git

Comment: I understand that, but both your examples didn't include a username, I just wanted to make sure you weren't forgetting that part.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it to reflect your concerns.